# Shrink a vmdk Virtualbox disk image

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBox is able to compact (reduce the size) of `.vdi` images but it is not possible with `.vmdk` disk images. But we can compact `.vmdk` files if we:

1. detach
2. convert to `.vdi`
3. compact
4. convert back to `.vmdk`
5. attach again to the original vitual machine

So I tried to shrink my VirtualBox image with this script:

```
#/bin/bash

VM_PATH=~/VirtualBox\ VMs
cd "$VM_PATH"
VM="$(ls ffnord-example_gc-gw0_* -d -1|head -n 1)"
cd "$VM"
VM_VDMK_NAME="$(ls *.vmdk -1|head -n 1)"
VM_NAME="$VM_PATH/$VM/$VM_VDMK_NAME"

echo reducing size of "$VM_NAME"
ls -lah "$VM_NAME"
set -x
vboxmanage showvminfo "${VM}"
vboxmanage storageattach "${VM}" --storagectl SATA --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium none
vboxmanage clonehd --format vdi "${VM_NAME}" /tmp/VM-disk.vdi
vboxmanage closemedium disk "${VM_NAME}" --delete
vboxmanage modifyhd /tmp/VM-disk.vdi --compact
vboxmanage clonehd --format vmdk /tmp/VM-disk.vdi "${VM_NAME}"
vboxmanage closemedium disk /tmp/VM-disk.vdi --delete
vboxmanage storageattach "${VM}" --storagectl SATA --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium 4/VMs/VM-disk1.vmdk
```

I adapted [this script from crysol](http://crysol.github.io/recipe/2013-10-15/virtualbox-compact-vmdk-images/) but it seems this is not working on Ubuntu? The first `vboxmanage storageattach` starts with an error right away:

```
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a controller named 'SATA'
```

If I try `"SATA Controller"` instead:

```
vboxmanage storageattach "${VM}" --storagectl "SATA Controller" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium none
```

I get this error:

```
VBoxManage: error: No storage device attached to device slot 0 on port 0 of controller 'SATA Controller'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "DetachDevice(Bstr(pszCtl).raw(), port, device)" at line 381 of file VBoxManageStorageController.cpp
```

If I comment out those `vboxmanage storageattach` lines, the script works fine, but the resulting VM is the same size as before and it doesn't boot anymore.

This is the [output of `vboxmanage showvminfo "${VM}"`](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/34ca2193355c3c73cd22)

Comment: Is it possibly attached to the VM as an IDE controller rather than a SATA controller?

Comment: Your VM doesn't have any storage attached, which is visible in the `showvminfo` output that you posted. Therefore, you're seeing this error message. I'm suspecting a previous, incomplete run of the script, as the first `storageattach` command detaches the VMDK file from your VM configuration:
`vboxmanage storageattach [...] --medium none`

Comment: Pretty good shrinkage is achieved by exporting the virtual machine as appliance from within VirtualBox. This creates an `.ova` file, which is just a TAR archive and thus can be extracted with `tar -xvf <appliance>.ova`. Within there is the disk as VMDK file, better compacted than `vboxmanage modifyhd --compact` does achieve for VDI files.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found a [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/582966/34298):

First inside the VM fill all free space with zeros:

```
cat /dev/zero > zero.fill;sync;sleep 1;sync;rm -f zero.fill
```

In your Host, install vmware-vdiskmanager from the [VMware Knowledge Base](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1023856):

```
cd /tmp/
wget http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/viewAttachment.do?attachID=1023856-vdiskmanager-linux.7.0.1.zip&documentID=1023856
unp 1023856-vdiskmanager-linux-7.0.1.zip
mv 1023856-vmware-vdiskmanager-linux.7.0.1 /usr/bin/vmware-vdiskmanager
chmod +x /usr/bin/vmware-vdiskmanager
```

Take care, that you have enough free disk-space before you start, you need the MV grows to double size during the process.

Then compress it with:

```
/usr/bin/vmware-vdiskmanager -k ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/<virtual disk.vmdk>
```

[Source](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-shrink-vmware-virtual-disk-files-vmdk)

Comment: Look here maybe you find another solution [http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/VMWare/A_12938-HOW-TO-Shrink-a-VMware-Virtual-Machine-Disk-VMDK-in-15-minutes.html](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/VMWare/A_12938-HOW-TO-Shrink-a-VMware-Virtual-Machine-Disk-VMDK-in-15-minutes.html)

Comment: @Quanlong the "Attachments" section at the end of the VMWare KB article which rubo77 linked has 3 versions of vmware-vdiskmanager.  The first is identified by Mac OS Finder as a Unix executable, and runs on at least El Capitan which I tested it on.

Comment: Cannot run this on Ubuntu 20 because `SSLLoadSharedLibrary: Failed to load library libcrypto.so.0.9.8` and that version cannot be installed because it is too old.

Comment: To resolve "failed to load libcrypto.so.... " need also add "lib" folder from the archive into LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Interestingly, `vmware-vdiskmanager -k` can also slightly *increase* the size of a VMDK disk. If I export a virtual machine from within VirtualBox as an appliance, it creates VMDK files which are smaller (roughly 75% the size of the VDI file I had for a 2G VDI disk) than the *compacted*(!) VDI files. If I run `vmware-vdiskmanager -k` on them, they increase slightly.

Answer (score 10):

I didn't need to install VMWare nor convert back to VMDK so I used

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-create-a-vagrant-base-box-from-an-existing-one#toc-make-the-box-as-small-as-possible

Inside the host:

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/EMPTY bs=1M
sudo rm -f /EMPTY
cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history && history -c && exit
```

Then after the guest is shut down:

```
$ vboxmanage clonehd --format vdi centos-7-1-1.x86_64.vmdk newdisk.vdi
$ ls -lh
-rwx------+ 1 Chloe None  39G Mar 26 14:52 centos-7-1-1.x86_64.vmdk
-rwx------+ 1 Chloe None  22G Mar 26 15:01 newdisk.vdi
```

It also allows compaction later

```
$ vboxmanage modifyhd newdisk.vdi --compact
```

Inside VirtualBox GUI, I selected 'Choose Virtual Hard Disk File' to select the new file.

Answer (score 8):

I could not get rubo77s solution above vmware-vdiskmanager solution to work, I believe it has dependencies on vmware workstation or vmware player, neither of which I have, I did find the executable and it gave me errors.

I was able to solve this by using his zero command

```
cat /dev/zero > zero.fill;sync;sleep 1;sync;rm -f zero.fill
```

then using virtualboxes export to .ova tool.

this will result in the ova stripping/compressing the zeroed space.
then you can re-import it.

Comment: this worked great with a windows 10 guest (sdelete.exe before exporting).
After reimporting the vm from the previously exported .ova file, the vmdk has a size of 80GB while inside the VM the 160GB-partition show  80GB of free space and an unused partition of 160GB. The original vmdk-file had a size of around 300GB
nest step is converting the disk to vdi and compacting it like in "@Chloe" answer

Comment: with a debian guest on a mac host, all i'm interested in is the size of the export file and this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

FYI:
as vmware modernized their knowledge base the download link is not valid anymore.

After some searching I found the zip attached with this link https://kb.vmware.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/068f4000009EgK0AAK

Which is included in the case
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1023856?lang=en_US&queryTerm=1023856

Also the binary was failing with a missing library in my Ubuntu but downloading
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openssl098/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.1_i386.deb and installing it was helping.

Basically this answer should just be a comment for [Shrink a vmdk Virtualbox disk image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309819/shrink-a-vmdk-virtualbox-disk-image/28391167#28391167) by rubo77 - but my reputation is too low so here you go.

Answer (score 0):

I got this oooold script which allows you to wipe out all the unnecessary data, inside of Windows on your partition. It's written in VBscript:

```
    `REM This script is published under the BSD Licence
REM http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php

Option Explicit

Const sDefaultDir = "C:\"
Const sDefaultFilename = "overwrite.garbage"
Const lStartBlockSize = 32768

Call Main

Sub Main()
  Dim sPath, sFilename
  Dim oArgs, oFS, oDrive, oRegExp, oMatches

  ShowStartMsg

  Set oArgs = WScript.Arguments
  Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  If oArgs.Count = 1 Then
    If oArgs(0) = "/?" Then
      ShowHelp true
    End If
  End If

  If oArgs.Count > 2 Then
    ShowMsg "ERROR: Invalid command line parameters (too many parameters specified)", true, true
  End If

  If oArgs.Count > 0 Then
    sPath = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName(oArgs(0))
  Else
    sPath = ""
  End If

  If oFS.FolderExists(sPath) Then
    WScript.Echo "Checking folder " & Chr(34) & sPath & Chr(34) & ": OK"
    If Right(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then
      sPath = sPath & "\"
    End If
  Else
    WScript.Echo "Checking folder " & Chr(34) & sPath & Chr(34) & ": FAILED"
    sPath = sDefaultDir
    WScript.Echo "INFO: Using default folder " & Chr(34) & sPath & Chr(34)
  End If

  If oArgs.Count = 2 Then
    sFilename = oArgs(1)
    If sFilename = "" Then
      ShowMsg "ERROR: Filename must not be empty", true, true
    End If
  Else
    sFilename = sDefaultFilename
    WScript.Echo "INFO: Using default filename " & Chr(34) & sFilename & Chr(34)
  End If

  Set oRegExp = new RegExp
  oRegExp.Pattern = "[\\\/\:\*\?\" & Chr(34) & "\<\>\|]"
  Set oMatches = oRegExp.Execute(sFilename)
  If oMatches.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Validating filename: OK"
  Else
    WScript.Echo "Validating filename: FAILED"
    ShowMsg "ERROR: Filename must not contain the following characters:"_
      & " \ / : * ? " & Chr(34) & " < > |", true, true
  End If

  If oFS.FileExists(sPath & sFilename) = False Then
    WScript.Echo "Ensuring that file " & Chr(34) & sFilename & Chr(34) &_
      " does not exist: OK"
  Else
    WScript.Echo "Ensuring that file " & Chr(34) & sFilename & Chr(34) &_
      " does not exist: FAILED"
    ShowMsg "ERROR: File " & Chr(34) & sPath & sFilename & Chr(34) & " already exists", true, true    
  End If

  Set oDrive = oFS.GetDrive(oFS.GetDriveName(sPath))
  If UCase(oDrive.FileSystem) = "NTFS" Then
    WScript.Echo "Checking for NTFS: OK"  
  Else
    WScript.Echo "Checking for NTFS: FAILED"
    ShowMsg "ERROR: " & oDrive.FileSystem & " file system not supported", true, true
  End If

  Select Case oDrive.DriveType
    Case 1, 2
      WScript.Echo "Checking drive type: OK"
    Case Else
      WScript.Echo "Checking drive type: FAILED"
      Select Case oDrive.DriveType
        Case 3
          ShowMsg "ERROR: Network drives are not supported", true, true
        Case 4
          ShowMsg "ERROR: CD-ROM drives are not supported", true, true
        Case 5
          ShowMsg "ERROR: RAM Disk drives are not supported", true, true
        Case Else
          ShowMsg "ERROR: Unkown drives are not supported", true, true
      End Select
  End Select

  If oDrive.FreeSpace > 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Checking for free space: OK"
  Else
    WScript.Echo "Checking for free space: FAILED"
    WScript.Echo "INFO: No free space available (no action required)"
    ShowMsg "INFO: Exiting Overwrite Script...", false, true    
  End If

  WScript.Echo "Creating garbage file " & Chr(34) & sPath & sFilename & Chr(34) & "..."
  CreateGarbageFile sPath & sFilename, oFS
  WScript.Echo "Garbage file successfully created!"
  WScript.Echo "INFO: " & oDrive.AvailableSpace & " byte(s) remained which could not be overwritten"
  WScript.Echo "Deleting garbage file..."
  oFS.DeleteFile sPath & sFilename
  WScript.Echo "Garbage file successfully deleted!"
  WScript.Echo "Exiting Overwrite Script..."
  WScript.Quit
End Sub

Sub CreateGarbageFile(sAbsFilename, oFS)
  Dim bSngByteBlock
  Dim sBlock
  Dim oFile, oDrive

  bSngByteBlock = false
  Set oDrive = oFS.GetDrive(oFS.GetDriveName(sAbsFilename))
  Set oFile = oFS.CreateTextFile(sAbsFilename, false, false)

  sBlock = String(lStartBlockSize, 0)
  On Error Resume Next

  Do While oDrive.FreeSpace > 0
    If oDrive.FreeSpace < lStartBlockSize Then
      If bSngByteBlock = false Then
        WScript.Echo "INFO: Falling back to single byte block"
        bSngByteBlock = true
        sBlock = String(1, 0)
      End If
    End If
    oFile.Write sBlock
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      WScript.Echo "WARNING: Error " & Chr(34) & Err.Description & Chr(34) & " ("_
        & Err.Number & ") occured while writing garbage file"
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop

  On Error GoTo 0
  oFile.Close
End Sub

Sub ShowStartMsg()
  WScript.Echo "Overwrite Script 1.0 (2004-09-05)"
  WScript.Echo "Copyright (C) 2004 Dennis Dietrich"
  WScript.Echo "http://www.myblog.de/scotty"
  WScript.Echo ""
  WScript.Echo "WARNING: The script is experimental. Use it at your own risk!"
  WScript.Echo "To cancel the execution of this script press CTRL + C"
  WScript.Echo ""
End Sub

Sub ShowMsg(sMsg, bShowHelpHint, bExit)
  WScript.Echo sMsg
  If bShowHelpHint = True Then
    WScript.Echo ""
    WScript.Echo "Use " & Chr(34) & "CScript Overwrite.vbs /?" & Chr(34) & " to get help."
  End If
  If bExit = True Then
    WScript.Quit
  End If
End Sub

Sub ShowHelp(bExit)
  WScript.Echo "Cleans free disk space from recoverable data by overwriting it with random"
  WScript.Echo "information. For a higher level of security execute this script at least three"
  WScript.Echo "times. Only NTFS partitions are supported."
  WScript.Echo ""
  WScript.Echo "CScript Overwrite.vbs [path] [filename]"
  If bExit = True Then
    WScript.Quit
  End IF
End Sub`
```

(inspired by  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/overwrite_script.aspx)